# Set node field value in separate form

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, files

I have a File field attached to my content type. Using Drupal, when we are creating new node, we use node form to set all field values for particular node. But is it possible to create more forms for editing one node? In particular, I need to setting File field values in separate page separated from node form.

For now, I do it with Form API, and hook_form_alter. For file field I can use form type "managed_file". 
 But is it possible with some existing module, using GUI? 
Could  I create separate form, where I can set just one (or few) fields of node (or entity, in general)?

EDIT: to explain it shortly. I would like to split node form to more forms. I would be able to set, which node fields would be set in which form.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i follow your narrative up there but you might be interested in entity metadata wrapper to help you deal with the objects and their states individually with custom forms.

https://drupal.org/node/1021556

The project page:
https://drupal.org/project/entity

Comment: thanks for hint. What I would need is split node form to more forms. I would be able to set, which node fields would be set in which form.